# Loop and create a Array from JSON Objects

Tags: android, json, eclipse, string, object

Hi i am working on an application which parses some `JSON` from their API. I got this working and it is shows all the information. The problem i am facing now is that i cant seem to get the `"FileID"` from the `JSON String`:

**The output is something like this:**

```
{ error: "", <fileId>: { infoToken: <string>, deleteToken: <string>, size: <int>, sha1: <string>, filename: <string> } }
```

The `"fileID"` is randomly generated for each file. how can i catch and parse that? i get all the other information just fine, only need to get the `"fileId"`

So, when thats done i want to collect all the information and put it into a `ListView`, i need to loop through every item received.

```
public class FilesActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private static String TAG_FILENAME = "filename";
    private static String TAG_SIZE = "size";
    private static String TAG_ITOKEN = "infoToken";
    private static String TAG_DTOKEN = "deleteToken";
    private static String TAG_SHA1 = "sha1";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dblist);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Files");

        String response = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://api.bayfiles.net/v1/account/files?session=<sessionId>");

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
               json.put("filename", "error");

               postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
               postMethod.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
               response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);
               TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nodata);
               JSONObject request = new JSONObject(response);
               for (Iterator<?> keyIterator = request.keys(); keyIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                   String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
                   JSONObject object = request.optJSONObject(key);

                   if (object != null) {
                       //Setting TAGs
                       TAG_FILENAME = object.getString("filename");
                       TAG_SIZE = object.getString("size");
                       TAG_ITOKEN = object.getString("infoToken");
                       TAG_DTOKEN = object.getString("deleteToken");
                       TAG_SHA1 = object.getString("sha1");            


                       txt.setText(
                               TAG_FILENAME + "\n"
                               + TAG_SIZE + "\n"
                               + TAG_ITOKEN + "\n"
                               + TAG_DTOKEN + "\n"
                               + TAG_SHA1 + "\n"
                               + txt.getText()
                               );                      

                       Log.d("log_tag", object.getString("filename"));
                   }
               }           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {      
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("log_tag", "Error: " + e.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: tried this, dont know if it will work tho:

```
ArrayList<fileObject> objectList = new ArrayList<fileObject>();
                   if (object != null) {

                       fileObject obj = new fileObject();

                       obj.setFileName(object.getString("filename"));
                       obj.setSize(object.getString("size"));
                       obj.setInfoToken(object.getString("infoToken"));
                       obj.setDeleteToken(object.getString("deleteToken"));
                       obj.setSha1(object.getString("sha1"));

                       objectList.add(obj);        

                       Log.d("log_tag", object.getString("filename"));
                   }
                   adapter = mView.new fileObjectAdapter(mContext);
                   setListAdapter(adapter);
                   adapter.addAll(objectList); //if honeycomb or higher
                   for (fileObject obj : objectList) {
                       adapter.add(obj);
                       }
```

and my adapter:

```
package com.dev.jsontest.adapter;


import com.dev.jsontest.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class fileObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<fileObject> {

    public fileObjectAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dbitems, parent, false);
        }

        final fileObject item = getItem(position);

        //define your view that you want each list item to look like. Make sure to set every field in your view.

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

fileObject:

```
package com.dev.jsontest.adapter;

public class fileObject {

    private String fileName;
    private String size;
    private String infoToken;
    private String deleteToken;
    private String sha1;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getInfoToken() {
        return infoToken;
    }

    public void setInfoToken(String infoToken) {
        this.infoToken = infoToken;
    }

    public String getDeleteToken() {
        return deleteToken;
    }

    public void setDeleteToken(String deleteToken) {
        this.deleteToken = deleteToken;
    }

    public String getSha1() {
        return sha1;
    }

    public void setSha1(String sha1) {
        this.sha1 = sha1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer your question in detail, but in general it might be helpful to let a framework doing all the parsing stuff :)

Maybe Jackson is something for you? (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Answer (score 0):

Why not rename `fileid` to `file` and make fileid a field within that array? (like `fileid: <fileid>`)

Or can´t you change the incoming JSON-String?

Comment: Hi, i cant change the incoming JSON, its an API i've asked them, but they wont ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "visit" all the keys (from first level) of your json.
 Try something like this:

```
String jsonString = "{ \"error\": \"\", \"<fileId>\": { \"infoToken\": \"<string>\", \"deleteToken\": \"<string>\", \"size\": \"<int>\", \"sha1\": \"<string>\", \"filename\": \"<string>\" } }";
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        Iterator<String> it = json.keys();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String key = it.next();

            if(!"error".equals(key)){
                String fileId = key;
                JSONObject fileIdJsonObj = json.getJSONObject(fileId);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```